# main.ERROR: Environment emulation nesting is not allowed. [] []

Tags: magento-2.1.7, system.log, environment-emulation

I got an error in **system.log**

> main.ERROR: Environment emulation nesting is not allowed. [] []

Why this came and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**First, you need to find out that from which email this  issue happening.**

If you have using **`startEnvironmentEmulation()`** in your custom email  then you should ensure that run **`stopEnvironmentEmulation`** () for `emulated environment after doing your work`.

May be `stopEnvironmentEmulation` is not called at your code.

**See some reference:**

https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-store-emulation/

Comment: I  m getting the same error message, even if i added the `stopEnvironmentEmulation` : (